# Does Ni(H2O)6 have Oh symmetry or Th?

Tags: water, coordination-compounds, transition-metals, symmetry, group-theory

I optimized a geometry of $\ce{Ni(H2O)6}$ using quantum chemistry and got a molecule which is symmetrical for the $\ce{Ni-O}$ distances as shown 
here:

[image: ball and stick model of Ni(H2O)6]

In the literature it says that this complex has an $\ce{O_h}$ point group, but this complex looks like it is $\ce{T_h}$. Do I need to revise my group theory or is what I am looking at actually a $\ce{T_h}$ point group?

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry StackExchange. It look like $T_h$  as drawn (ignoring bonds  to H atoms, and considering all atoms are fixed), but without any H it is $O_h$. Additionally the OH group is going to rotate more or less freely so its average will be the same as if H atoms are ignored.

Comment: In addition to the Hydrogen atoms swirling around, wasn't the tetrahedral symmetry $T_h$ a subgroup of the octahedral $O_h$, too?